# grafana logql query using line_format and regexReplaceAll dynamically

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

I need to read my logs just like they were displayed in the application console.

My grafana LogQL query looks like this :

```
{job="myjob", host="myserver"} 
| json 
| line_format `{{ regexReplaceAll "{(.*?)}" .MessageTemplate "{{.Properties_${1}}}" }}`
```

It ouputs a json object, I would like to use the "MessageTemplate" property and replace all the bracketed variables back where they belong so the log is readable in grafana log dashboards.

[image: It doesn't replace like I would want to]

My problem is when using `regexReplaceAll("<regexp>" <String_To_search> <output>)` you cannot parse the output as a variable. Is there a way to do this that I missed ? I've tried hundreds of combinations and parsed through [the official documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/template_functions/#regexreplaceall-and-regexreplaceallliteral).

Please let me know if it's impossible !

Answer (score 0):

Try using [label_format](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#labels-format-expression) instead of [line_format](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#line-format-expression). The first one replace the content of a label (or create a new one), so you can use its output.

```
{job="myjob", host="myserver"} 
| json 
| label_format MessageTemplate=`{{ regexReplaceAll "{(.*?)}" .MessageTemplate {{.Properties_${1}}}" }}`
| <whatev you want to do with MessageTemplate>
```